# Microphone.names not providing the correct list of mics

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm writing a program that uses a microphone in AS3. I want to keep the selected microphone information in a "cookie" so that if the user visits the page several times, he doesn't have to choose the mic again and again.

I have noticed that Firefox and Explorer give me the correct list of microphones available via `Microphone.names`, but Chrome does not. Does anyone know why?

If you want to reproduce the error, you can follow these steps:

1. Connect a USB microphone to your computer.
2. Run a flash program where you display the `Microphone.names` list.
3. Unplug the USB microphone.
4. Run the flash program again, and you will see that even though the USB mic is 
   disconnected, it is still displayed in the microphone list.

Comment: Do you quit out of the browser and make sure its not running after unplugging the microphone? I've found that was necessary to make Flash realize the mic (or camera) has changed.

Comment: How do you do that? How can I notify to Flash that the mic was unplugged?

Comment: Before start running the application, I connect the mic and after that I start the application. The first time it displayes me the list but that mic is not there. How can I notify to Flash that the mic was (un)plugged?

Comment: Could I mess somehow the Flash-player? I'm trying to use another applications that require the usb-mic and it just does not work the usb-mic. But that is just happening in Chrome :S

Comment: The only way I've found to notify Flash that a mic or camera was removed was to quit the browser. When you do that the underlying Flash process goes away. The next time your start the browser, the Flash process will start again and check the system for mics/cameras. Note, detecting mics/cameras may behave differently (I think the mics are particularly stubborn and require the browser process to be terminated). Also, it's possible that other applications have grabbed the mic/camera and can prevent Flash from detecting it. The behavior may vary based on OS and Flash Plugin you are using.

Comment: Finally, Chrome uses a new Flash plugin called "Pepper Flash" which is very buggy. You can disable that by going to chrome://plugins. You will likely have other Flash plugins installed in Chrome, and those may behave differently. Pepper Flash, unfortunately, is not very stable right now (my opinion).

Comment: It was because I'm using the new Flash plugin called "Pepper Flash". I disable that one and it seems that everything is working fine now. Thanks! If you put it as an answer I'll vote it as the final one. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pepper Flash is [Adobe and Google's effort](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/02/adobe-and-google-partnering-for-flash-player-on-linux.html) to keep Flash player alive on the Linux platform. It is used by all recent versions of Chrome on all OS's by default.

Unfortunately, there are quite a few problems with Pepper Flash. I've noticed a handful of bugs on the Mac and Windows platforms, regarding webcams and microphones. Others have seen issues with various video games.

When ever someone reports a Flash problem that only occurs in Chrome, Pepper Flash always seems to be the culprit.

Fortunately, if you are not running Linux you can still install the regular Flash Player plugin (the "netscape" plugin) on Chrome (or you likely have one already installed).  Pepper Flash can be disabled in Chrome by going to the url: chrome://plugins.